Can I connect an external screen/monitor to a QU-24?
I use an Allen & Heath Qu-24 for my church, and I'm wondering if we could extend the screen of our console to an external screen (like HDMI,VGA or something).
Is this possible? (and, if so, how?)

According to their own website they don't offer any video out capability, so it looks like a no.

Sort of. The ipad application can do most of the things the internal screen can. That adds an external screen.


According to their own website they don't offer any video out capability, so it looks like a no. - Rory Alsop [comment]

